# Can't load IA 32-bit .so on a IA 32-bit platform

Tags: linux, centos, java

I'm trying to install an 32_bit_application on CentOS (64-bit), while running the `setup.bin`
file it return the following error

```
Invocation of this Java Application has caused an InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)

Stack Trace:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/install.dir.28410/Linux/resource/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: Can't load IA 32-bit .so on a IA 32-bit platform
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraries(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.DebugHelper.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.util.BidiUtilImpl.setDefaultLocale(DashoA10*..)
        at ZeroGbb.a(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.q(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.b(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.a(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(DashoA10*..)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
        at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)
This Application has Unexpectedly Quit: Invocation of this Java Application has caused an InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)
```

please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Could be a missing dependency. Look at the output from `ldd /tmp/install.dir.28410/Linux/resource/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install libXp:

```
yum install libXp
yum install libXp.i686
```

Comment: its working @Eder